# Couldn't find a Program\n at Scope.getProgramParent

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs

After installing `expo-sms` on my bare react-native app, Im unable to run my app as it keeps prompt this error:

```
Couldn't find a Program\n at Scope.getProgramParent 
(/path/to/my/app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:864:11)
```

Anyone faces this error before?